# Spread operator not working on Objects with string as key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Im writing some code atm with ES6 and Babel (es2015 preset) and I cant spread one Object as I am used to. Normally I would take an Object, use a spread and map the inner content like `[...someObject].map(dosomestuff)`. But my one object does not behave as expected and the only difference I found so far are the keys:

```
let myObject = {
  'key': content,
  'key2': content,
  'key3': content
};

let array = [...myObject];
```

Since the object gets generated form a file structure, the keys are formed by variables and can include special chars, so i need to set them like `object[key] = value`. Why cant I use the spread operator on that object (the array is always empty)? And is there a workaround thats as comfortable as the spread-operator (I dont mean making a new Array with Object.keys and use that)

Comment: What is the desired result here?

Comment: I want get an array that i can map like [content, content, content].map(doSomething)

Comment: You can `map()` keys to values or use `Object.values(myObject)`

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508) *"Why cant I use the spread operator on that object"* You can only use a spread *element* when that element is *iterable*. Objects are not iterable.

Answer (score 6):

The object `spread` works on bojects, you can't spread an object into an `array`.

You should `spread` it to another object:

```js
let myObject = {
  'key': "content1",
  'key2': "content2",
  'key3': "content3"
};

let myObject2 = {
  'key4': 'content4'
}

let newObj= {...myObject, ...myObject2};
console.log(newObj);
```

This is not part of ES6, but it is on [stage 3](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread)

Comment: This is invalid ES6.

Comment: using `babel` https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: Sure, but how should somebody deduce that from your answer?

Answer (score 2):

> Why cant I use the spread operator on that object?

First of all, [`...` is not an operator!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper/37152508#37152508).

You can only use a spread *element* when that element is *iterable*. Objects are not iterable.

> And is there a workaround thats as comfortable as the spread-operator (I dont mean making a new Array with Object.keys and use that)

Not in ES6.

I am assuming that you want to get the property *values* from the object.

If you don't wan to write a helper function and don't necessarily want to use a spread element, you can actually make use of `Array.from`'s ability to take a mapping function as second argument:

```
Array.from(Array.keys(myObject), x => myObject[x]);
```

If you really don't want to use `Object.keys` (`Object.values` doesn't exist in ES6), then you can write yourself your own helper function as a generator:

```js
function* values(obj) {
  for (var x in obj) {
    // You can use `obj.hasOwnProperty(x)` to guard against inherited properties
    // to achieve the same effect as `Object.keys`
    yield obj[x];
  }
}

let myObject = {
  'key': 'content',
  'key2': 'content1',
  'key3': 'content2'
};

console.log([...values(myObject)]);
// or
console.log(Array.from(values(myObject)));
```

Answer (score 0):

With Chrome I see that using spread on an object results in an exception. What does work is using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)